# Spring MVC SimpleFormController

Tags: model-view-controller, spring

I have a **SimpleFormController**, the doSubmit() is doing nothing but populating a command object(call it bar, a simple POJO, and it have a field, say id). So, the successView is being called.
the successView is "redirect:/foo.html", and the bean def for foo.html is:
    
I have this bean mapped to a simple jsp, called foo.jsp.
the jsp comes up fine.
my issue is that I want foo.jsp to show `${bar.id}`, it is not showing up.
when I do not do a redirect, `${bar.id}` shows up fine. what do I need to do to get it to work in a "redirect" situation?

Comment: Why not just skip redirect and assign your foo.jsp as successView?

Comment: You can reference this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249049/how-to-pass-parameters-to-redirect-page-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing bean def:

```
<bean name="/foo.html"class=".....UrlFilenameViewController"/>
```