# How to pass parameters to redirect page in spring-mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have wrote following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logOut", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String logOut(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)  {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "success logout");
        System.out.println("/logOut");
        return "redirect:home.jsp";
    }
```

How to change this code that on page `home.jsp` I can to write `${message}` and to see `"success logout"`

Comment: Do you have a controller mapped to handle `home.jsp`? Your flahs attribute is added correctly.

Comment: A `redirect` sends a 302 response back to the client with a `Location` header. In your case that `Location` will be some url to `home.jsp`. You need to have a handler for that. Do you?

Comment: is it redirecting to `home.jsp`?

Comment: it is unreally without handler ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the return value contains `redirect:` prefix,  the `viewResolver` recognizes this as a special indication that a redirect is needed. The rest of the view name will be treated as the redirect URL. And the client will send a new request to this `redirect URL`. So you need to have a handler method mapped to this URL to process the redirect request.

You can write a handler method like this to handle the redirect request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String showHomePage()  {
    return "home";
}
```

And you can re-write the `logOut` handler method as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logOut", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String logOut(Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)  {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "success logout");
    System.out.println("/logOut");
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can avoid `showHomePage` method with this entry in your application config file:

```
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 .....
 xsi:schemaLocation="...
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 ....>

<mvc:view-controller path="/home" view-name="home" />
 ....
</beans>
```

This will forward a request for `/home` to a view called `home`. This approach is suitable if there is no Java controller logic to execute before the view generates the response.

Comment: I made mistake. I want to avoid showHomePage method. My viewResolver has usual configuration :class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
              <property name="prefix">
                 <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
              </property>
              <property name="suffix">
                 <value>.jsp</value>
              </property>

Comment: home.jsp is sibling of WEB-INF